# Need help identifying this anime from about 18 years ago

Tags: jigoku-sensei-nube

I remember watching this when I was a little kid, but I barely remember anything at all. The main character was a man with a "demon arm" that he always keeps hidden with a glove, the moment he takes off the glove his hand activates granting him great power. The episode that I remember watching had a little girl singing in a black, dream-ish environment.

If I recall, I watched one episode in Spanish dub and the girl sang this song as she played: "dos y dos son cuatro cuatro y dos son seis". I know it's not a lot of information, but it's always been bugging me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The premise sounds like [Jigoku Sensei Nube](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2012/Jigoku_Sensei_Nube).

> Nube is a clumsy, easygoing, and very kind teacher, but he has a secret under his glove on the left hand. He has a monster hand, and he also has the ability to sense ghosts and evil spirits. So he protects his dear students from these evil spirits with his monster hand, proving to be very powerful.

[image: Nube's glove on] [image: Nube's glove off]

Comment: YES! The arm looks very familiar, this is it! Thank you.

Comment: @Shelby.S: No problem =)

Comment: For reference, the Spanish title of this anime is apparently [_Nube, el Maestro del Infierno_](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1087).